# Binding input range to specific cell in angular table

Tags: angularjs, html-table, 2-way-object-databinding

In Angular I have this simple model:

```
$scope.rdata = [
    {1: 7, 2: 23,3: 9, 4: 13,5: 32},
    {1: 23, 2: 8,3: 67, 4: 11,5: 6},
    {1: 35, 2: 12,3: 24, 4: 17,5: 24},
    ];
```

I render it in html using ng-repeat:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <p>Example of xy data rendered</p>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rdata">
          <td ng-repeat="c in col">
            <div>{{row[c]}}</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="range" id="example" min="0" max="1" step="0.01">
          </td>
          <td><div>
            Value compiled: {result of input range value * value in row[c]}
             </div></td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically I would like to bind the Value displayed in the last div of my last  (where Value compiled is written) as the product of the input range value in the same row and the value in the last column of the same row.
If possible, I would like to understand if there is a way to reference whatever value located in column x and row y and be able to interact with it, put it in a formula etc... without building another angular model.

Let me know if it is sufficiently clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Edit:
my data is a bit more like this:

```
$scope.financials2 = [ { '2011': 98, '2012': 97, '2013': 100, name: 'Sales' },
  { '2011': -5, '2012': -6, '2013': -7, name: 'Costs of Goods Sold' },
  { '2011': 93, '2012': 91, '2013': 93, name: 'Gross Profit' },
  { '2011': -37, '2012': -36, '2013': -35, name: 'Operating Expenses' },
  { '2011': 54, '2012': 55, '2013': 58, name: 'Operating income' } ]
```

I may need to restructure the format of the data. The idea is by row I show concepts like Sales, Gross Profit etc... and Values are displayed in columns grouped by years

So the intermediate stage would be like:

```
Concept            2011 2012 2013
Sales                98   97  100
Cost of Goods Sold   -5   -6   -7
Gross Profit         93   91   93
```

The idea is I would like to add two columns,

- one with a slider (input range) for every row, which show growth
  rates, so basically an input range going from -0.05 to +0.05
- another column showing 2014 forecasts: so Sales 2014 = Sales 2013 * (1+ slider value), Gross Profit 2014 = Gross Profit 2013 * (1+ Slider value)

So we have 2 additional columns, with the first one containing sliders for every row and the second columns showing the result of the 2013 columns times the slider values.
Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two pieces it seems you are trying to get here. The first is how do you get the value in the input field, and the second how do you get row[c].

For the input field, you can append the value of the input into your row using ng-model.

For your object it is best to define names for each value, rather than just `{1:1, 2:3, 3: 4}`, otherwise, just use an array. In the example provided, I called your last item in the object `last` in this jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/reszjcu2/ - warning, the formatting is pretty crap.

Note, I had to provide key and value for the row object, as ng-repeat only works with arrays, not objects. Another reason to use an array if you aren't going to actually have named items in your object.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure about your jsfiddle link? it looks pretty empty, just showing Hello superhero!, I'll edit my question so it's more precise.

Comment: sorry, I had forked sombody elses fiddle, and apparently didn't update. http://jsfiddle.net/ak6k1gh7/2/ try this one.

Comment: I think the principle is there, however when I modify the html to  Value compiled: {{ (1 + row.range||0.5) *  row.last}}   it seems to  give me wrong values, would you know why? That's ok if you don't, I  will post another question on Stackoverflow then. Thx for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "wrong values". My version says `multipley row.range x row.last. If row.range does not exist, use 0.5`. Do you need to change 0.5 to 1.5?

Comment: I have modified the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ak6k1gh7/3/ to reflect the desired output. I treat row.range as a growth rate, so I changed the range and the calculation, it gives some strange results, notably when you click on th first slider, given the last value is 32 and the range value is 0.03, it gives a for the calculation (32 * (1+ 0.03)) a value compiled of 320.96 instead of 32.96 and if I put the slider below 0 (as my range goes from -0.05) it gives me null.

Comment: @Bondifrench, this is programming, you need to be able to debug these sorts of things. Your calculation is strange. Why are you adding 1 to -0.05 instead of just using a range of 0.95 -> 1.05? I've updated the fiddle once again, putting the range calculator into a function in the controller to make it easier to play with and see what is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/ak6k1gh7/5/

Comment: Thanks @pedalpete this is a classic calculation in financial modelling http://macabacus.com/operating-model/income-statement-projections, the slider is a growth rate, sales 2014 forecasts = sales 2013 Actual * (1+ growth rate). I guess the main point is to get the function into the controller.

Comment: @Bondifrench putting the function in the controller rather than in the html is cleaner, and makes it easier to play with. I often make these decisions based on how complicated the function will be and if it will be used in more than one place, etc. etc.